# Does forge api abe to extract the same amount of properties as the revit api?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

I would like to know if this [forge api](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/src/Autodesk.Forge/Api/DerivativesApi.cs) can extract the same amount of properties in a revit file as the revit api does?
What I noticed when using forge api (DerivativesApi.cs) is that some properties were not present compared to the result of revit api. For example this material area, material thickness, material ifcguid, etc, is not in the extracted data using forge api.

Is there a way I can extract more data like revit api does in forge api?

Comment: Appending to what Jeremy said:

If the properties (called parameters in Revit API) you're looking for require the user to do more clicks on the Revit UI, then, the answer is obviously and simply NO. By current design, Model Derivative API doesn't extract nested parameters.

Answer (score 0):

No, obviously not. The Autodesk APS platform is a generic CAD model viewing and analysis platform. To enable that, the seed model needs to be tremendously compressed and brought into a generic format, removing a lot of the domain-specific modelling data required in a BIM or mechanical model. So, the answer is obviously and simply NO.